# Extract row from a matrix in a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, extract, rows

I'm trying to extract rows from all the matrices in a list in R. Is there an easy way to do this other than looping? For e.g.,

```
set.seed(123)
list1 <- list(replicate(4,rnorm(2)))
rep(list1,3)
```

This code generates the following list:

```
[[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.5604756 1.55870831 0.1292877  0.4609162
[2,] -0.2301775 0.07050839 1.7150650 -1.2650612

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.5604756 1.55870831 0.1292877  0.4609162
[2,] -0.2301775 0.07050839 1.7150650 -1.2650612

[[3]]
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.5604756 1.55870831 0.1292877  0.4609162
[2,] -0.2301775 0.07050839 1.7150650 -1.2650612
```

Now I want to extract 2nd row of all the matrices in this list and store it in another matrix or list. Is there a way to do this without looping?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or like this?

```
set.seed(123)
list1 <- list(replicate(4,rnorm(2)))
l<-rep(list1,3)
lapply(l,function(x) x[2,])
```

Comment: using lapply retrieves a list. Taking your same idea: `t(sapply(l,function(x) x[2,]))` retrieves a matrix

Comment: Just changing up the syntax a little: `t( sapply(l,'[',2,TRUE) )`

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix(unlist(lapply(x,function (x) { x[2,]})),nrow=length(x), byrow=T)

           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.2372892 0.8751748 -0.5452381 -0.1484494
[2,] -0.2372892 0.8751748 -0.5452381 -0.1484494
[3,] -0.2372892 0.8751748 -0.5452381 -0.1484494
```

Answer (score 1):

This extracts the rows with `lapply` and puts them together with `rbind`.

```
x = rep(list1,3)
do.call( rbind, lapply(x,'[',2,) )
```

The `plyr` package is another option

```
library(plyr)
laply(x,function(y) y[2,])
```

The `?"["` help page is enlightening. After reading it, I realized the very short, simple code below also works.

```
laply(x,'[',2,TRUE)
```